# Ввод в консоль несколько строк на Java

Tags: java, scanner

Например у меня есть текст:

```
Hello
Hello2
Hello3
```

Я его выделяю и вставляю в консоль.
Как получить ввод?

К примеру

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
String buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    buffer=br.readLine();
    if (buffer.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
    if (!line.toString().equals(""))
        line.append(" ");
    line.append(buffer);
}
```

И для того чтобы ввести строки (Hello,Hello2,Hello3) нужно еще нажать Enter, а нужно без него

Comment: При использовании Scanner и BufferedReader не получилось реализовать.

Comment: прочитайте строки с консоли 3 раза. А лучше покажите код и покажите что именно не получилось.

Comment: @Виктор добавил пример

Comment: Если последнюю строку надо читать без Enter то как определить, что ввод закончился в вашем случае?